# Do the Tok'ra use any particular gate address for their ceremony?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In Season 6 Episode 9 - *Allegiance* we see the Tok'ra use the Stargate to farewell their dead in a ceremony by having them vaporized by the opening Stargate.

I am wondering if the Tok'ra use any gate address at all or if there is a particular address they use and if so what significance does this address have for them?

Answer (score 5):

### We don't know.

The ceremony is really only ever shown in the one episode, "Allegiance: Part 1", that you mentioned. (I confirmed this by searching through scripts of all episodes with Tok'ra in them, rather than relying upon memory.)

However, all we see is that the gate has already been dialed off-screen , and the wormhole is merely activated on-screen. We don't get do see any of the runes being selected, in any order, or any chevrons being encoded. I watched and rewatched the scene, but there's clearly no additional details to be had.

My guess is that they simply dial one of their other occupied or allied planets, where they can be sure the gate will dial and not garner any unwanted attention.

Answer (score 1):

We can make an educated guess according to Stargate lore: the Tok'ra would have knowledge of the physics involved in a Stargate. They would know matter caught in the initial "burst" of an establishing wormhole would not travel through the wormhole to the destination gate (as illustrated by other episodes like the soldier committing suicide and not ending up on the destination planet, or General "we don't leave people behind" Hammond would have ordered the body to be retrieved).

In addition, I can't remember any reference to the Tok'ra mentioning an afterlife or a holy place like the Jaffa think of Geb or Dakara.

Based on this lore, it would seem useless to dial a specific gate address for the ceremony.

Comment: Don't the gates need a valid address in order to generate the kawoosh? Would it just be down to the Tok'ra in charge of dialing the gate to choose an address at random? It might be a bit embarrassing if the gate didn't lock (either because the target is buried or currently active) and they had to waste time dialing another address. Rather than being useless, I would've thought it would be quite useful to check with the other end to make sure the destination gate isn't busy or running diagnostics etc at the scheduled time.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, that's a good point, of course they would pick a valid address and maybe even do a rehearsal on beforehand. My point was, there is no reason in the lore for it to consistently be the same or a specific set of addresses, e.g. a Tok'ra Geb.

Comment: I'm mixing my Egyptology with Gua'ould, that's Kheb in stead of Geb of course.